# Available Notifications For NSDistributedNotificationCenter

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, safari, nsnotification

I was looking for a list of Distributed Notifications that exists on mac like iTunes com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo but I couldn't find anything. I was wondering if other applications like Safari or QuickTime does have such notifications? And if they exists what are their notification names?

Regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By adding an observer and setting it's name to nil it will show all the notifications.

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(observerMethod:) name:nil object:nil];
```

I didn't find anything special.

Comment: This seems like it stopped working at least on Xcode 13.2.1 and/or macOS 12.3.1. When I do specify "com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo", it does work.