# Cocoa / NSUserNotificationCenter get all NSUserNotification notifications

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, nsusernotificationcenter

How can I be notified whenever *any* application delivers or activates an `NSUserNotification`?

- Neither could I determine anything that is sent via `NSDistributedNotificationCenter`,
- nor could I find a mask like `NSUserNotificationDeliveredMask` [dummy name] I could register a global `[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask]` for,
- nor does there seem to be a suitable observer for the default user notification center object.

The `[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` and its delegate only notify me when my own app delivers a notification.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437149/available-notifications-for-nsdistributednotificationcenter) should address how to receive available notifications from `NSDistributedNotificationCenter`. There [doesn't seem to be any way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761077/is-there-any-way-of-knowing-how-many-nsusernotifications-there-are-in-nsusernoti) to get all `NSUsernotifications` as far as I know, though.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. You can only listen to `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` for "global" notifications. The app developer has to broadcast to `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` for you to hook into it.

You can't hijack other applications Notifications. Most apps and all apps distributed through App Store is sandboxed. The very nature of this limits your ability to hook into them!